# Unique ID for individual users linked to form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a multi-user site that will allow users to add information that won't be viewable by anyone else but that user.  I have a `userid` field in db table 'users' that will auto-generate the userid, and I need that `userid` associated with the information that is being posted and that `userid` will also need to be used when retrieving and viewing that information.

Please help, clearly I'm new at this.

-- RESOLVED! --

Since many of you aided in helping BAN me from this site, please review the code that I have done my *own* research on and got to work. In fact, this method was the SIMPLEST one that I found. After using $_SESSION['myusername'] to set and retrieve the username from the login screen, in order to insert the username into the clients or payments db table this was what I used:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="<? echo $_SESSION['username'] ; ?>">
```

BAM! Carries it over and it acts as a line in the form INSERTS it like the other form field data.

Comment: I think the problem here was that, above your `-resolved-` line, there wasn't nearly enough information to guess what you needed. Seeing your solution gives me a, "Ah, right!" sort of feeling, but it'd have been a lucky guess if someone had offered that as the answer. Remember when asking a question, you should ask yourself: "What information would readers need to help answer this?".

Comment: Now that this has been answered, I'll vote for this to be reopened, so you can rollback your answer edit and insert your answer as, well, an answer. If other people are in agreement, then it will get reopened. Note that people have not deliberately tried to ban you - that is a consequence of asking questions that were unanswerable. But do not worry, this situation can be reversed!

Comment: I totally get that...and I promise that I will try to be clearer and include any code snippets that I might have to help direct the answer-er to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a userid field in your other tables where the data is stored, then when you are displaying the data make sure that your query includes a where clause with the userid of the current user.

Comment: Thank you, Moov Tony.  WHERE userid = ### correct?

Comment: Thanks...however, I'm having trouble RETRIEVING that to my form.  I added:  $result = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = ".$_GET['username']."") ;  however, it's not working...any suggestions?

Comment: I'm also trying to display the userid on the screen and added: 
echo $result ; where I wanted it to be displayed...but it doesn't work!  I'm sure because I'm an IDIOT...thanks